# Vulkan flickering for small meshes

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, vulkan

I am rendering different models. Big models (more than a thousand triangles) are rendered without issue, however small models(a single triangle, or 12 triangles) flicker.

The way I am currently rendering involves 2 passes, so I assume the flickering comes from an absence of proper barriers.

The execution goes:

1. start to render pass,
2. render to texture (image attachment of FB),
3. stop pass.
4. start pass,
5. render to main display
6. end pass.

There is only a single global graphics queue. Following the vulkan tutorial, I have a command buffer for every image in my swapchain, and I record commands to each buffer in that list, like so:

```
    for(auto &cmd : cmd_buffers)
    {
        std::array<vk::ClearValue, 2> clears = {};
        clears[0].color = vk::ClearColorValue(array<float, 4>({0,0,0,0}));
        clears[1].depthStencil = vk::ClearDepthStencilValue(1.0f, 0.0f);
        vk::RenderPassBeginInfo render_pass_info(
            *render_pass, *(framebuffers[index]), {{0,0}, extent},
            clears.size(), clears.data()
        );

        cmd.beginRenderPass(&render_pass_info, vk::SubpassContents::eInline);
        index++;
    } 
    /* submit more instructions to the command buffers later */
```

For the off screen target (FB) I only record a single command buffer.

I call my first render pass as described above, and then, immediately before calling the second render pass, I try waiting on an image barrier:

```
void RenderTarget::WaitForImage(VulkanImage* image)
{
    vk::ImageMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
    // TODO(undecided): maybe this isn't always true
    barrier.oldLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eShaderReadOnlyOptimal;
    barrier.newLayout = vk::ImageLayout::eShaderReadOnlyOptimal;
    barrier.srcAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eShaderWrite;
    barrier.dstAccessMask = vk::AccessFlagBits::eShaderRead;
    barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.image = image->GetImage();
    barrier.subresourceRange =
        vk::ImageSubresourceRange(vk::ImageAspectFlagBits::eColor, 0, 1, 0, 1);

    vk::CommandBuffer command_buffer = h_interface->BeginSingleTimeCommands();
    command_buffer.pipelineBarrier(vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eAllGraphics,
        vk::PipelineStageFlagBits::eFragmentShader, {}, 0, nullptr, 0,
        nullptr, 1, &barrier);
    h_interface->EndSingleTimeCommands(command_buffer);
}
```

And then somewhere else in the code I call it:

```
    display_target.WaitForImage(&image);
    active_target_id = 0;
    display_target.StartFrame();
    render_presentation.AddDrawData(quad_buffer, {uniform_data},
        {{&image, 1}});
    display_target.EndFrame();
```

Based on the behaviour I have seen, I assume my issue is a synchronization problem, however, the image barrier code doesn't seem to solve the flickering.

Am I using the barrier wrong? Should I look into other possible sources of error (and if so, which)?

Comment: Well, what happens if you use the [debug barrier](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples#full-pipeline-barrier) instead?

Comment: I just figured this out 45 minutes ago, it was due to a wrong image presentation index being used for presentation. The one mystery is why this problem only exhibited itself for small meshed but not big.

I am not sure if I should delete the question or update it

Comment: I am voting to close this as "typo, and not useful for future users". Probably not worth your time to adjust the question and self-answer in a way useful to other users. But that's up to you. Could be interesting why the mesh size matters though...

Comment: I am not sure how easy it will be to find the reason why big meshes change the behaviour. But since wrong image presentation is UB, as far as I know, it is potentially useless for people in other systems.

On any case, I too voted to close it, hopefully that;s the right thing to do.